# ANT task for calling Karma/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ant, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

While searching the internet it seems that Grunt is the preferred task runner for executing AngularJS test under Karma/Jasmine.  Our project has server side java code and browser side javascript code.  We already have a full unit test suite for the Java code, which we use ANT to run this suite.  I have written some unit tests for our Javascript using Karma, Jasmine and PhantomJS.  For CI, I would like to run these Karma scripts the same way that we do the Java scripts, which again is ANT tasks.  Having a hard time finding an ANT task for runnig Karma.  Would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and was able to achieve this with the following ANT code:

```
<target name="unittest">
    <exec executable="karma">
        <arg line="start karma.conf.js"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```